# Bootstrap Modal disappears immediately

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a terms & conditions modal I'm trying to display on a bootstrap page. The modal show's for a split second when the link is clicked but then the page just goes black and I have to refresh. Any ideas?

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background: gray;text-align: center;font-size: 10px;color: white;" >
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" style="color: white;">
        Terms and Conditions
    </a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="openModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-content" style="color: black;text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

                 TEXT TEXT TEXT

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us how you launch the modal plz

Comment: Try changing: data-target=".modal" to data-target="#openModal"

Comment: @Christina You can target a modal with a class name. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

Comment: with folks on SO you never know whether they have more than one on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal can't be part of your navbar.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/wjfo8kL2/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background: gray;text-align: center;font-size: 10px;color: white;" >
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" style="color: white;">
        Terms and Conditions
    </a>
</div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="openModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-content" style="color: black;text-align: left;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

                 TEXT TEXT TEXT

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice how I've clsoed off the div for your navbar. Once you do that and the modal is outside of it, it'll pop just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myLauncher').click(function(){
    $('#openModal').modal();
});
```